How to display a DropDownList as a partial view inside an ASP.NET Core MVC Kendo Grid?
I want to display a dropdown in an ASP.NET Core Kendo Grid. In "CarsViewModel", I already have the values ​​that need to be displayed as a dropdown, so I don't need to make an Ajax call to get the dropdown values. I just want to call my PartialView that renders the dropdown.
Here is my code for the grid:
@model CarsViewModel

<div>
    @(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<CarRowViewModel>(Model.Car)
        .Name("car-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //Columns
            columns.Template(
            $"<partial name=\"_Model\" model=\"#= @item #\" />"
            ).Title("Model Number").Width(200);
        })
        .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true).Height("auto"))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Excel();
            toolbar.Search();
        })
        .Excel(excel =>
        {
            excel.FileName($"{Model.Cars}.xlsx");
            excel.AllPages(true);
        }))

</div>

Here is my partial view which I am calling:
@model CarRowViewModel

<select asp-for="SelectedModelNumber" asp-items="@Model.CarModelNumber"
        class="form-select" id="modeNumbers" title="Decision">
    <option selected disabled hidden>----- Select -----</option>
</select> 

When I run this code, it does not display a dropdown for Model Number column. How do I render my partial view dropdown in kendo grid and get it to bind?

maybe you can try ClientTemplate? and the partial view should be something similar to @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)? Here's the demo link, please click the "View source" to see the demo codes.

It is better to use "External Kendo UI Template".
I usually prefer Ajax Call to provide data in Kendo Grid but for this question which is to fill data using model, let's consider the following codes. These codes are just examples to illustrate the point. Of course, these codes need to be modified and completed for the actual program.
ASP .NET Core Page:
@model CarsViewModel
<div>
    <script id= "ColumnTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        @Html.Partial("_ModelNumber", Model.Cars.First())
    </script>
    <script>   
        var ColumnTemplateFunction = kendo.template($('#ColumnTemplate').html());
    </script> 
    @(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<CarRowViewModel>()
        .Name("car-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CarName);
            columns.Template("#=ColumnTemplateFunction(\"\")#").Title("Model Number").Width(200);
        })
        .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true).Height("auto"))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Excel();
            toolbar.Search();
        })
        .Excel(excel =>
        {
            excel.FileName($"{Model.CarListName}.xlsx");
            excel.AllPages(true);
        })
        .BindTo(Model.Cars)
    )
</div>

CarRowViewModel:
public class CarRowViewModel
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public string? SelectedModelNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>? CarModelNumber
    { 
        get
        {
            return GetCarModels(CarName);
        }
    }
    public static List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem> GetCarModels(string CarName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CarName))
            CarName = "Car";
        return new List<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>() {
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Text = CarName + "_Model_1", Value = CarName + "_1" } ,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Text = CarName + "_Model_2", Value = CarName + "_2" } ,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem() { Text = CarName + "_Model_3", Value = CarName + "_3" } ,
        };
    }
    public CarRowViewModel(int carId, string carName, string selectedModelNumber = "")
    {
        CarId = carId;
        CarName = carName;
        SelectedModelNumber = selectedModelNumber;
    }
    public CarRowViewModel()
    {
        CarId = 0;
        CarName = "";
        SelectedModelNumber = "";
    }
}

CarsViewModel:
public class CarsViewModel
{
    public int CarListId { get; set; }
    public string CarListName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CarRowViewModel>? Cars { get; set; }
    public CarsViewModel(int carListId, string carListName, IEnumerable<CarRowViewModel>? cars)
    {
        CarListId = carListId;
        CarListName = carListName;
        Cars = cars;
    }
    public CarsViewModel()
    {
        CarListId = 0;
        CarListName = "";
        Cars = null;
    }
}

Action Method:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var Cars = new CarsViewModel
        (
            1, 
            "FirstList", 
            new List<CarRowViewModel>()
            {
                new CarRowViewModel(1, "Car 1"),
                new CarRowViewModel(2, "Car 2"),
                new CarRowViewModel(3, "Car 3"),
                new CarRowViewModel(4, "Car 4"),
            }
        );
        return View(Cars);
    }
}

It should be noted that the appropriate parameters were not assigned to the partial view with the above approach. The following code can be used to transfer the appropriate parameters completely if the number of car types is not large. Of course, it is not an ideal method.
ASP .NET Core Page (To pass the appropriate parameters to the partial view):
@model CarsViewModel
<div>
    @{
        <script>
            var ArrayOfColumnTemplateFunctions = []
        </script> 
        foreach(var Car in Model.Cars)
        {
            <script id= "@string.Format("ColumnTemplate_{0}", Car.CarId)" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                @Html.Partial("_ModelNumber",  Car)
            </script>  
            <script>
                CurrentColumnTemplateFunction = kendo.template($('#ColumnTemplate_@Car.CarId').html());
                ArrayOfColumnTemplateFunctions.push(CurrentColumnTemplateFunction);
            </script> 
        }
        <script>
            ArrayOfColumnTemplateFunctions.reverse();
        </script>
    }
    @(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<CarRowViewModel>()
        .Name("car-grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.CarName);
            columns.Template("#=ArrayOfColumnTemplateFunctions.pop()(CarId)#").Title("Model Number").Width(200);
        })
        .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true).Height("auto"))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true))
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Excel();
            toolbar.Search();
        })
        .Excel(excel =>
        {
            excel.FileName($"{Model.CarListName}.xlsx");
            excel.AllPages(true);
        })
        .BindTo(Model.Cars)
    )
</div>

